# embed MapView into Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to embed MapView into FrameLayout of an activity for example ,

**UserActivity** layout

```
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/map_frame" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:padding="0.0dip" android:clipChildren="true" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip">  
       <ImageView android:id="@+id/map_img" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_width="294.0dip" android:layout_height="136.0dip" android:src="@drawable/place_map_frame" />
</FrameLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Here , inside FrameLayout i want to display MapView when ever the list item gets clicked
for some reason its not possible to directly put inside framelayout so just because of that i created another activity which extends MapActivity

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
android:layout_gravity="center" 
android:id="@+id/mapview" 
android:clickable="true" 
android:layout_width="294.0dip" 
android:layout_height="136.0dip" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

**UserMap** layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/mapview" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="294.0dip" android:layout_height="136.0dip" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:apiKey="@string/google_maps_key" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the code for both the activities

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserMap extends MapActivity {


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.user_map);


    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class UserActivity extends Activity {


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.user_activity);                          
    }

}
```

Now , i want to embed a UserMap into UserActivity's FrameLayout and UserActivity will be called when a list item get clicked.

Comment: make your `UserActivity` a `MapActivity`

Comment: if i extend MapActivty in UserActivity then , when i called it as an intent , its giving me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ui.user.UserActivity error

Comment: is it ok for `UserMap` ? can you open `UserMap` ?

Comment: if i directly call UserMap then the issue is same NoClassDefFoundError as its also extending MapActivity may be android doesn't consider MapActivity as a normal Activity

Comment: `MapActivity` is child of `Activity`, you probably missing something in your configuration, [Here are posts related to this discussion](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+NoClassDefFoundError+in+MapActivity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to include the Google API instead of the single Android API.

You also need to include the following line in your Manifest, under the `<application>` tag:

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Comment: Build Path was bothering me !